# Parse name from the object and display-Angular Js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, scope

My object(Unparsed and raw):

```
   $scope.result= {
        "id": 2360,        
        "subject": "Meeting Postponed Status",
        "message": "{\"name\":\"Riana\",\"status\":\"Postponed\",\"meeting\":\"Approval No 342\",\"postponedDate\":\"2015-06-24 18:30:00\",\"postponedTime\":\"13:02:57\"}",   
        "modifiedDate": "2015-06-29 17:09:59",
        "categoryId": 1,    
    }
```

I'm parsing the property `message` of `$scope.result` object as

`$scope.result=JSON.parse($scope.result.message);` which outputs `$scope.result.message` as

```
$scope.result.message={"name":"Riana","status":"Postponed","meeting":"Approval No 342","postponedDate":"2015-06-24 18:30:00","postponedTime":"13:02:57"}
```

But if I want to bind the name `Riana` I'm not able to do it in the HTMl
I tried by giving {{result.message.name}} but not able to render the name.
Is there a way to parse in the HTML as I'm unable to do it in the controller?

Comment: Can you show us your html codes?

Comment: Its like this {{result.message.name}}

Comment: What do you get for {{result}} and {{result.message}}

Comment: For {{result}}: {
    "subject": "Meeting Postponed Status",
    "message": "{\"name\":\"RianaMinny\",\"status\":\"Postponed\",\"meeting\":\"Approval of Mining Site area No 342\",\"postponedDate\":\"2015-06-24 18:30:00\",\"postponedTime\":\"13:02:57\"}",
    "modifiedDate": "2015-06-29 17:09:59",
    "categoryId": 1             
   
}

Comment: and {{result.message}} :{"name":"Riana","status":"Postponed","meeting":"Approval No 342","postponedDate":"2015-06-24 18:30:00","postponedTime":"13:02:57"}

Comment: result.message is still a string, rather than an object from the look of {{result}}. Are you sure the JSON.parse line is being run and the result being assigned. Also, check if you console.log it you should get an object (in Chrome it'll start with Object {... not just {...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **assign** the `JSON.parse($scope.result.message)` to `$scope.result.message`.

**E.g.**

```
$scope.result.message = JSON.parse($scope.result.message);
```

**Here's the [JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/qnatn60v/4/)**.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well after this statement.

```
$scope.result=JSON.parse($scope.result.message);
```

your **$scope.result** object look this

```
Object {name: "Riana", status: "Postponed", meeting: "Approval No 342", postponedDate: "2015-06-24 18:30:00", postponedTime: "13:02:57"}
```

In HTML you should use like this

**{{result.name}}**  and

not like this one **{{result.message.name}}**

Comment: @Riaj Khan the name is inside the message object

Comment: are you want to two way data binding with name?